How to upload apk files to input file in HTML/PHP
When I upload any apk files that are bigger than 16MB to <input type=‘file’>(within <form action=“” method=“post”> ) and hit the submit button the web just load for some bit then refreshes the page and resets every  datas that are put into the other inputs  earlier as if nothing happened.
Or we can say this in another way, how can I make the form to be able to transfer big sized files such as apks.
I have searched in google, youtube and found nothing related to that problem.

Have you  set the enctype attribute of the form to multipart/form-data? Have you investigated and modified settings within the PHP ini that govern max upload size see here

@ProfessorAbronsius it certainly worked just fine! Thanks professor. Would be happy if you post it as an answer and I’ll mark it as the asnwer.

Possible issues such as incorrect form setup, missing enctype="multipart/form-data", or problems within your PHP code could be the culprit. If all your HTML and PHP code seems correct but you still encounter upload limitations, two factors to consider are upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. These limitations are set in your server's php.ini file, and if you're facing issues, increasing their values might resolve your problem. Typically, errors are displayed for this issue. You can refer to this page for further reading on configuring file upload settings in PHP.
